# How to make unstructured array of object to row?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

`c.data` is jsonb object, like this: `{programs:[{...},{...}]}`

`c.data->'programs'` is jsonb array, like this `[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3,d:4}]` or `null`

Already tried this:

```
SELECT p
FROM Clients c , jsonb_array_elements(c.data->'programs') p
```

or this

```
SELECT p
FROM Clients c , jsonb_array_elements(COALESCE(c.data->'programs','[]'::JSONB)) p
```

but it shows an error:

```
[22023] ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar
```

how can I retrieve the object inside `data->'programs'` as rows of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON path instead, using the `jsonb_path_query` function.

```sql
SELECT p
FROM Clients c
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(c.data, '$.programs') p
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fd5c33acf22aa39b3240a53d47998959)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the answer, must filter the null first

```
SELECT p
FROM Clients c, jsonb_array_elements(c.data->'programs') p
WHERE (c.data->>'programs') <> 'null'
-- or LENGTH(c.data->>'programs') > 0
```